# OpenVPN auto-reconnect after network down in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

How to setup OpenVPN automatically reconnect after network down in Ubuntu 18.04?
Already set `keepalive 60 180` (ping interval = 60, ping restart = 180) but this settings has no effect. 10+ min no re-connection until i do it manual.

[image]

Comment: You could use my `net-o-matic` script. https:https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

Comment: I hope it must be some native solution! @waltinator, in any case thanks. Can You explain more detailed how your script is works? I mean it must be run with cron or it start like a daemon when user run it from command-line? Do need sudo or not?

Comment: "Native solution"? It's a `bash` script. You could start it manually, or via a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`. Read the script. I tried to write it cleanly, with explanatory comments.

Comment: When I told about "native solution" i mean some GUI checkbox "Autostart when down after ..". It strange to see when Ubuntu network manager translate all OpenVPN configs to GUI with check-boxes and selects, but still have no solution to set it reconnect with same GUI.

Answer (score 0):

In `terminal`, type `nm-connection-editor`, and select your wired/wireless connection profile, and edit like this...

[image]

Comment: Yep, already set it: https://i.imgur.com/UBqrH8g.png But looks like this solution to connect VPN on boot automatically, but not for network down.

Comment: @mature when set to "automatically connect" my wired connection comes back up with VPN... I don't know if it works that way with wireless? Which are you using?

Comment: I use Wired connection